# How do I convert Float to Int When Necessary?

Tags: swift, xcode, casting, floating-point, int

So, I'm pretty new to swift and Xcode and might be missing something obvious, but I've done a bit of research, and can't find my answer.
My code is:

```
for number in currentList {  
listPreview.text = "\(listPreview.text!) \(String(number))"      
}
```

The problem is, the *Numbers* in *currentList* are Floats. But if my user were to input a number that *isn't* a float, it will display as:

```
"UsersNumber".0
```

I want it to display as just:

```
"UsersNumber"
```

However, if the number the user gave me was a float, say... 1.2, I would still want it to display as 1.2 .

is there some kind of extension that can do this?

Like an if-statement saying

```
if number.isUselessFloat {
code
}
```

Thanks in advance, 
-Another Nooby user

Comment: Lookup NSNumberFormatter ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let number1 = 1.0
    let number2 = 1.2

    let str = String(format: number1 == floor(number1) ? "%.0f":"%.1f", number1)
    print(str)
    //prints 1

    let str2 = String(format: number2 == floor(number2) ? "%.0f":"%.1f", number2)
    print(str2)
    //prints 1.2
```

Comment: You have copied the answer from the first answer link's

Comment: This truncates to at most one decimal digit, e.g. 1.234 is printed as 1.2.